# Sending an email-id in HTML code using Sendgrid API

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, sendgrid, email-client

When I'm sending the Email id using the HTML. It is visible in browser G-mail but it is not visible in the Outlook and Apple Email client. This is a sendgrid email template.

```
<div style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 150%; margin: 0px; text-align: left;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">
        <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; decoration:none;" href="mailto: :useremail">
            Sender Email::useremail
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :-

```
<div style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 150%; margin: 0px; text-align: left;"><a target="_blank" style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto: :useremail">Sender Email: :useremail</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is you're using a `span` as a mailto link. As that is not valid HTML, some clients could be ignoring it/removing it or it could be breaking the styles for that element.

All of the style could be applied to an `a` element like so:

```
<a href="mailto: :useremail" target="_blank" style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; text-decoration:none;">Sender Email::useremail</a>
```